# Summoning Div from database in foreach - asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, foreach

I got database row like this "val1-val2-val5" and in my aspx page i got 5 div (their id's val1,val2,val3... etc) all of them visible false. I want visible them true with information based database row.

I use this method ;

```
 string query = @"SELECT [Params]     
 FROM [Products] WHERE Id = '"+id+"'";
        string result= Library.Database.ExecuteScalar(query).ToString();

        string[] results;
        results= result.Split('-');

        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            switch (item)
            {
                case "val1": val1.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case "val2": val2.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case "val3": val3.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case "val4": val4.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case "val5": val5.Visible = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I wonder if there is a way to do this without "switch-case", for example

```
    foreach (Literal item in results)
      {item.visible = true }
```

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. You can try something like this.

```
foreach(var item in results)
{
Control Div_In_the_Page = FindControl(item);
if(Div_In_the_Page  != null)
    Div_In_the_Page.visible = true;
}
```

thats just a mock up of what you can try. Im not entirely sure of

```
 Div_In_the_Page.visible = true; //dont know if this will work. Else just use the css attributes to sort that out
```

one thing that you need to make sure of with divs when you want to edit them from server side is make sure that the div has this attribute

```
<div runat="server"><!-- put things in here --></div>
```

Comment: Div_In_the_Page is coming null nomather what.